# How do I use Ansible loop register values?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-template

I am trying to `grep` the process IDs for a process on multiple target hosts and trying to kill that process.

What I have so far is this

```
- name: Grep any running process
  shell: ps aux | grep "[m]ongo*" | awk '{ print $2 }'
  register: mongod_running_processes
  with_items:
  - "{{ groups['primary-server-gb4'] }}"
  - "{{ groups['replication-servers-gb4'] }}"
```

Now I want to kill the processes in the target host.

```
- name: Delete process
  shell: kill -15 {{ item }}
  with_items: "{{mongod_running_processes.results.stdout_lines}}"
```

This does not seem to be working.

---

Q. How do I get the target specific process ID array and kill the processes?

Comment: I absolutely don't get what you are trying to do. The loop in your first task does not make any sense. You are not using the `item` anywhere. Are you trying to list those processes on each server in the groups ? If yes, you are missing a `delegate_to` clause. And in this case, your second task does not make any sense either. since you are trying to kill all tasks several times on a single server that is probably not running them (besides the fact that the var you loop on does not exists since `results` is a list).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can kill the process using a one liner, because you are already using the "shell" 
module:

Replace:

```
shell: ps aux | grep "[m]ongo*" | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

for:

```
shell: ps aux | grep "[m]ongo*" | awk '{ print $2 }' | xargs kill -15
```

and disregard following task.